# Visual basic temperature conversion program displaying incorrect values

Tags: vb.net

I haven't programmed in visual basic in years but I have this code that is suppose to convert temperatures from fahrenheit to celcius. The problem is when you enter a number into one of the text boxes, you get repeating numbers and the values are incorrect. I think it has something to do with the Handles but I am pretty lost here, any ideas?

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub FahrenheitTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FahrenheitTextBox.TextChanged
        CelciusTextBox.Text = 5 / 9 * (Val(FahrenheitTextBox.Text) - 32)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CelciusTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CelciusTextBox.TextChanged
        FahrenheitTextBox.Text = (9 / 5 * (Val(CelciusTextBox.Text)) + 32)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What do you mean by "repeating numbers"? Do you have an example of an incorrect value?

Comment: For example. If I run the code, click in the Fahrenheit text box and type '32' the numbers that show up in the celcius text box are not right. Something like 10.33333333333. After text has entered I can't delete it either

Comment: Not being able to delete text is probably from the battling TextChanged events. Take care of that, and then see what happens with your conversions.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, per se, but I wanted to make some suggestions that will not show up well in a comment. If you are using the TextChanged event, you should guard against unwanted events, e.g., typing into one text box, which fires TextChanged, which causes the other text box to change, firing TextChanged, causing the text box you're typing into to change.

Try something like this:

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private textChanging As Boolean = False

    Private Sub FahrenheitTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FahrenheitTextBox.TextChanged
        If Not textChanging Then
            textChanging = True
            CelciusTextBox.Text = 5 / 9 * (Val(FahrenheitTextBox.Text) - 32)
            textChanging = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CelciusTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CelciusTextBox.TextChanged
        If Not textChanging Then
            textChanging = True
            FahrenheitTextBox.Text = (9 / 5 * (Val(CelciusTextBox.Text)) + 32)
            textChanging = False
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Also, you should use `CStr` to convert from a number to a string, in the same way you use `Val` to convert from a string to a number:

```
Private Sub FahrenheitTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FahrenheitTextBox.TextChanged
    If Not textChanging Then
        textChanging = True
        CelciusTextBox.Text = CStr(5 / 9 * (Val(FahrenheitTextBox.Text) - 32))
        textChanging = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally, I've re-tagged your question - this is VB.NET, not VB6. Thanks!